# I wrote the Matrix Multiply CUDA program, but it always got the wrong answer compared with my CPU result?

Tags: c, cuda

```
// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <shrQATest.h>
#include <time.h>
#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC ((clock_t)1000)

// Variables
float* h_A;
float* h_B;
float* h_C;
float* h_C_cpu;
float* d_A;
float* d_B;
float* d_C;
bool noprompt = false;

// Functions
void CleanupResources(void);
void RandomInit(float*, int);
void ParseArguments(int, char**);
void ZeroInit(float*, int);
// Device code

__global__ void MatrixMul(const float*A,const float*B,float*C,int Arow,int Acol,int Bcol)
{
    int coli= blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int rowi= blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;
    float tmp=0;
    C[rowi*Bcol+coli]=0;
    for(int k=0;k<Acol;k++)
    {
        if(rowi<Arow&&coli<Bcol)
            C[rowi*Bcol+coli]+=A[rowi*Acol+k]*B[k*Bcol+coli];
    }
    //__syncthreads();
    //C[rowi*Bcol+coli]=tmp;
}

// Host code
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    shrQAStart(argc, argv);
    clock_t start,end;
    double duration;
    printf("Vector Addition\n");
    int a_row=800,a_col=600,b_row=600,b_col=900;
    int a_size =a_row*a_col* sizeof(float);
    int b_size=b_row*b_col*sizeof(float);
    int c_size=a_row*b_col*sizeof(float);
    //const int matrixrow=10000,matrixcol=10000;


    h_A=(float*)malloc(a_size);
    h_B=(float*)malloc(b_size);
    h_C=(float*)malloc(c_size);
    h_C_cpu=(float*)malloc(c_size);
    RandomInit(h_A, a_size/sizeof(float));
    RandomInit(h_B, b_size/sizeof(float));
    //memset(h_C,0,c_size);
    ZeroInit(h_C,c_size/sizeof(float));
    //memset(h_C_cpu,0,c_size);
    ZeroInit(h_C_cpu,c_size/sizeof(float));
    //RandomInit(h_C, c_size);
    start=clock();
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<a_row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b_col;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<a_col;k++)
            {
                h_C_cpu[i*b_col+j]+=h_A[i*a_col+k]*h_B[k*b_col+j];
            }
        }
    }
    end=clock();
    duration=double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("CPU time: %lf\n",duration);



    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A,a_size));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B,b_size));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C,c_size));


    ParseArguments(argc, argv);

    // Allocate input vectors h_A and h_B in host memory
    /*h_A = (float*)malloc(size);
    if (h_A == 0) CleanupResources();
    h_B = (float*)malloc(size);
    if (h_B == 0) CleanupResources();
    h_C = (float*)malloc(size);
    if (h_C == 0) CleanupResources();*/

    // Initialize input vectors


    // Allocate vectors in device memory
    /*cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, size) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, size) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, size) );*/
    start=clock();
    // Copy vectors from host memory to device memory
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, a_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, b_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // Invoke kernel
    //int threadsPerBlock = 1024;
    dim3 dimblock(32,32);
    int blockx = (b_col + dimblock.x - 1) /dimblock.x;
    int blocky = (a_row + dimblock.y - 1) /dimblock.y;
    dim3 dimgrid(blockx,blocky);

    MatrixMul<<<dimgrid, dimblock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C,a_row,a_col,b_col);


    //myVecAdd<<<1,threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A,d_B,d_C,N);
    cutilCheckMsg("kernel launch failure");
#ifdef _DEBUG
    cutilSafeCall( cutilDeviceSynchronize() );
#endif

    // Copy result from device memory to host memory
    // h_C contains the result in host memory
    cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, c_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
    end=clock();
    duration=double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("GPU time: %lf\n",duration);
    // Verify result
    for (i = 0; i < a_row*b_col; ++i) {
        //float sum = h_A[i] + h_B[i];
        if (fabs(h_C[i] - h_C_cpu[i]) > 1e-5)
        {
            //printf("The result is wrong!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    CleanupResources();
    shrQAFinishExit(argc, (const char **)argv, (i==a_row*b_col) ? QA_PASSED : QA_FAILED);
}
void ZeroInit(float* a, int N)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        a[i]=0;
}
void CleanupResources(void)
{
    // Free device memory
    if (d_A)
        cudaFree(d_A);
    if (d_B)
        cudaFree(d_B);
    if (d_C)
        cudaFree(d_C);

    // Free host memory
    if (h_A)
        free(h_A);
    if (h_B)
        free(h_B);
    if (h_C)
        free(h_C);

    cutilDeviceReset();
}

// Allocates an array with random float entries.
void RandomInit(float* data, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

// Parse program arguments
void ParseArguments(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--noprompt") == 0 ||
            strcmp(argv[i], "-noprompt") == 0) 
        {
            noprompt = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my CUDA code: "MatrixMul.cu", My project has only this one file, and I write it in the SDK, VectorAdd project, just modify it. I wrote the kernel function and the main function in one *cu* file.

I compared the result with my CPU result,finding that it's not same. Another problem is, when I used the tmp variable instead of the C[rowi*matrixcol+coli], it's also wrong, I also don't know why?

Comment: The NVIDIA CUDA SDK contains a [matrix multiply example](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#matrixMul) that you might want to look at.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues in your code that I found.  First of all, in your kernel you are not properly conditioning the code on valid thread indices.  The valid thread indices are those which correspond to actual result matrix elements.  The invalid thread indices are those which are outside this area.  You have a check for this, but it's in the wrong place in the code.  Instead of this:

```
C[rowi*Bcol+coli]=0; 
for(int k=0;k<Acol;k++) 
{ 
    if(rowi<Arow&&coli<Bcol) 
        C[rowi*Bcol+coli]+=A[rowi*Acol+k]*B[k*Bcol+coli]; 
}
```

Use this:

```
if(rowi<Arow&&coli<Bcol)  {
  C[rowi*Bcol+coli]=0; 
  for(int k=0;k<Acol;k++) 
    { 

        C[rowi*Bcol+coli]+=A[rowi*Acol+k]*B[k*Bcol+coli]; 
    } 
}
```

Due to the way your code was written, some threads outside the valid range were zeroing some elements when they should not have been due to this line of code that was before your valid thread check:

```
C[rowi*Bcol+coli]=0;
```

The second issue I found is that your equivalence check is probably too tight.  Where you had this:

```
    if (fabs(h_C[i] - h_C_cpu[i]) > 1e-5)
```

I changed it to this:

```
    if (fabs(h_C[i] - h_C_cpu[i]) > 1e-4)
```

And with the above changes I was able to get a matching result. You can fiddle with the equivalence check to see how many matching digits there are, but yours was expecting too many matching digits for a 32bit float quantity.  Your residual check here is not scaled, and as a result you cannot be as tight as you might think.  If you create a scaled residual check, then you can be certain of checking for a given accuracy on each element.

As a further suggestion, in your results comparison loop, I would change the following line:

```
        //printf("The result is wrong!\n");
```

To:

```
        printf("The result is wrong at idx: %d CPU: %f GPU: %f\n", i, h_C_cpu[i], h_C[i]);
```

In order to get more useful results if you want to play with it further and things go wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!It's right now,but when I increased the scale from MatrixA(2000*1000)*MatrixB(1000*1500),the Nvidia driver just crashed,is it that my GPU memory is too small for this scale?

Comment: If you run out of GPU memory, one of those cudaMalloc statements will throw an error, which the cutilSafeCall() should catch and display.  I don't think that's it.  My guess is you are hitting a [windows TDR event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx).  Since you're timing the GPU portion, try making the matrix sizes smaller and look at the execution time.  Then gradually increase the matrix sizes to increase the execution time until you approach 1-2 seconds for GPU time.  If you get a crash as you go over about 2 seconds GPU time, its a TDR event.

Comment: The main component of GPU memory that is needed for this code is storage of the matrices A, B, C.  Even with your larger sizes, A takes 2000*1000*sizeof(float) storage, so approx. 8 MB.  C is the largest at 2000*1500*4, approx 12MB.  The sum of all 3 of these is probably much much smaller than your available GPU memory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!That's the reason,I think, and should I modify something to change the Windows 7 setting?